# How to apply re.findall to a file giving empyt list

Tags: python, regex, list

I have text file below:

`Is there any way to do removing the empty list while using re.findall`

```
Started : Sunday, May 1, 2016 1:59:16 PM
Source : C:\RegularExpressionsWithDotNet\robocopytest\source\தமிழ்\हिन्दी\English
Dest : C:\RegularExpressionsWithDotNet\robocopytest\destn\
Started : Sunday, May 1, 2016 1:59:16 PM
Source : C:\RegularExpressionsWithDotNet\robocopytest\source\தமிழ்\हिन्दी\English
Dest : C:\RegularExpressionsWithDotNet\robocopytest\destn\
```

My Code is below:

```
with open(r'C:\debug.log', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fr:
    eachline = fr.read()
data = [eachline.strip() for eachline in eachline.splitlines()]
datalinelist = []
for i in data:
    datalinelist.append(re.findall(r'\bSource : (.+)', i))
datalinelist
```

My Out is `[[],
 ['C:\\RegularExpressionsWithDotNet\\robocopytest\\source\\தமிழ்\\हिन्दी\\English'],
 [],
 [],
 ['C:\\RegularExpressionsWithDotNet\\robocopytest\\source\\தமிழ்\\हिन्दी\\English'],
 []]`

Is there any way to do removing the empty list while using re.findall

If i am doing `[line for line in open(file,'r',encoding='utf-8') if re.findall(r'Source : .+',line)]`

I am getting proper out `['Source : C:\\RegularExpressionsWithDotNet\\robocopytest\\source\\தமிழ்\\हिन्दी\\English\n',
 'Source : C:\\RegularExpressionsWithDotNet\\robocopytest\\source\\தமிழ்\\हिन्दी\\English\n']`

What is the error in processing `with` condition

Comment: Don't give 50 bounty for this:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(r'debug.log', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fr:
    eachline = fr.read()
data = [eachline.strip() for eachline in eachline.splitlines()]
datalinelist = []
for i in data:
    datalinelist.extend(re.findall(r'\bSource : (.+)', i))
datalinelist
```

['C:\RegularExpressionsWithDotNet\robocopytest\source\?????\??????\English',
 'C:\RegularExpressionsWithDotNet\robocopytest\source\?????\??????\English']

Answer (score 0):

There are a few improvements you can do.

1. Loop over the file line by line, rather than calling `f.read()` and `str.splitlines`.

   This is the main difference between what you in the list comprehension and using `with`
2. Replace the `re.findall` calls by compiling the regex and then calling it's `findall` method.
3. Use the truthiness of lists to ignore empty results.

```py
source = re.compile('\bSource (.+)')

data = []
with open(r'C:\debug.log', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        sources = source.findall(line)
        if sources:
            data.extend(sources)
```

In the end, `data` should contain all of the paths you were looking for.

Comment: Great answer, although the `if` is redundant

Answer (score 0):

Can you please extend the list instead of appending? your source code should be like as below:

```
datalinelist = []
for i in data:
    datalinelist.extend(re.findall(r'\bSource : (.+)', i))
datalinelist
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the below?

```
with open(r'C:\Debug.log', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fr:
    eachline = fr.read()
data = [eachline.strip()[9:] for eachline in eachline.splitlines() if re.findall(r'\bSource : (.+)', eachline) != []]
print(data)
```

Gives me the output:

[image]